# R sqlSave - how to specify column Names

Tags: sql-server, r

Quite baffled by this.

I want to append rows into SQL server from a dataframe - but the verbose output from executing this is letting my know that it is using EVERY column in the table to insert

(verbose output)
    Query: INSERT INTO "Products" ( "ID", "ParentProductID"..etc.. all columns ) VALUES ( ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,? )

I have tried it with no colnames.  The error is always:

Error in odbcUpdate(channel, query, mydata, coldata[m, ], test = test,  : 
  missing columns in 'data' - but only the amount

```
sqlSave(sqlOdbc, insertRows, tablename = "Products", 
append = TRUE, verbose = TRUE, 
colnames = c("Code","DefaultSupplierSku","Name","Size","DefaultSupplierID","BrandID","ProductTypeID","BuyPrice","SellPrice")
)
```

Comment: what is sqlSave ?

Comment: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RODBC/versions/1.3-14/topics/sqlSave